# Lock Orientation for SAPUI5 FIORI App

Tags: sapui5

Is there a way to lock the orientation of a SAPUI5/FIORI App to always landscape? Not sure if changing the orientation via jquery and some css will work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless its an native application you can't.

But you can do hack showing a message to go landscape mode when user is in portrait mode.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #warningContent { display: none; }

    @media only screen and (orientation:landscape){
        #warningContent { display:none; }
    }
    @media only screen and (orientation:portrait){
        #content { display:none; }
        #warningContent { display:block; }
    }
</style>


<div id="content">
    <!-- your SAPUI5 app goes here-->
</div>
<div id="waringContent">
    This SAPUI5 app is only viewable in landscape mode. Please change the orientation.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with UI5 app properties.